# How do you target an element that is dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Without using 'on' or 'setInterval' or 'setTimeout' (none of them works), how do I change the text of an element that is dynamically generated after a certain button is clicked. So far I've tried the setInterval combined with setTimeout but it didn't work.

```
$("#buttontoclick").click(function(){
  var changeElement = setInterval(function() {
      var targetElement = $(".parentclass").find(".dynamicallygeneratedclass");
      if (targetElement.length) {
        clearInterval(changeElement); changeElement = 0;
          targetElement.text('this is the new text');
      };
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (changeElement) {
        clearInterval(changeElement); changeElement = 0;
      } else if (!changeElement) {
      };
    }, 5 * 1000);
  });
});
```

I've also tried binding the dynamically generated child element with static parent element using 'on' but it didn't work either.

```
$(document).on('mouseover mouseout', '.dynamicallygeneratedclass', function(){
  $('.dynamicallygeneratedclass').text('this is the new text');
});
```

Comment: would be easier to help if you can add the related html code + setup this as a runnable snippet(even if it contains errors).

Comment: sorry I've already tried that approach as mentioned on my question. I've basically tried using 'on' and using 'setInterval' and 'setTimeout.'

Comment: Try `$(this).text('this is the new text');` in your second example.

Comment: I tried that too unfortunately it didn't work either.