# Without using 'on' or 'setInterval' or 'setTimeout' , how do I change the text of an element that is dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, jquery

Without using 'on' or 'setInterval' or 'setTimeout' (none of them work), how do I change the text of an element that is dynamically generated after a certain button is clicked. So far I've tried the setInterval combined with setTimeout but it didn't work.

```
$("#buttontoclick").click(function(){
  var changeElement = setInterval(function() {
      var targetElement = $(".parentclass").find(".dynamicallygeneratedclass");
      if (targetElement.length) {
        clearInterval(changeElement); changeElement = 0;
          targetElement.text('this is the new text');
      };
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (changeElement) {
        clearInterval(changeElement); changeElement = 0;
      } else if (!changeElement) {
      };
    }, 5 * 1000);
  });
});
```

I've also tried binding the dynamically generated child element with static parent element using 'on' but it didn't work either.

```
$(document).on('mouseover mouseout', '.dynamicallygeneratedclass', function(){
  $('.dynamicallygeneratedclass').text('this is the new text');
});
```

Comment: It isn't clear why you are using `setInterval` and `setTimeout`, and you haven't explained that, but they have nothing to do with targeting dynamic elements.  Using [delegated event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/on/), as you are doing in your 2nd code snippet, is correct.  Have you added some debugging to check if that handler is firing? Have you tried attaching to a parent HTML element, rather than `document` (just guessing - the mouse is *always* over the browser so how would it enter or leave?).

Comment: [Your duplicate question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747692/how-do-you-target-an-element-that-is-dynamically-generated) was closed as a dup, because it is.  If you're still having trouble, try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - eg you haven't shown us your HTML, nor the code which generates your dynamic elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your div with class `dynamicallygeneratedclass` is empty
if its empty then mouse over and mouse out function wont work
you can use CSS to set width and height of div

```js
$(document).on('mouseover mouseout', '.dynamicallygeneratedclass', function() {
  $('.dynamicallygeneratedclass').text('this is the new text on first div');
});

$(document).on('mouseover mouseout', '.secondDiv', function() {
  $('.secondDiv').text('this is the new text on Second Div');
});
```

```css
.secondDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="dynamicallygeneratedclass">dummy text</div>

  <div class="secondDiv"></div>
```